# avx512F kmovw mov word by word

Tags: assembly, x86, avx512

i have a question about AVX512F - kmovw instruction.
i have a 8-BYTE mask in K0 register which it's possible to use 'kmovq' and move it to a 8-BYTE register or reserved memory (8-BYTE). but 'kmovq' works only in AVX512BW and for AVX512F, we need to use 'kmovw'. but this instruction moves only 16 bits so we need to move the mask 4 times now which one is correct ?

```
sub     esp, 8
kmovw   ax, k0
... (do the job with AX)
kmovw   ax, k0 + 2
... (do the job with AX)
kmovw   ax, k0 + 4
... (do the job with AX)
kmovw   ax, k0 + 6
... (do the job with AX)
add     esp, 8
```

or

```
sub     esp, 8
kmovw   ax, [k0]
... (do the job with AX)
kmovw   ax, [k0 + 2]
... (do the job with AX)
kmovw   ax, [k0 + 4]
... (do the job with AX)
kmovw   ax, [k0 + 6]
... (do the job with AX)
add     esp, 8
```

in fact my question is about how using k0 word by word ... using [] or just plus it with N

**for example,**

this code works in AVX512BW (because of 'kmovq')

```
vmovdqu64       zmm0, [rax]      ; rax = string
vpcmpeqb        k0, zmm0, zmm1   ; zmm1 = 0
kortestq        k0, k0
...
...
kmovq   rbx, k0
tzcnt   rbx, rbx
add     rax, rbx
```

but if i want to use only AVX512F, what should i do with 'kmovq'?

Comment: `vpcmpeqb` requires AVX512BW - it uses byte granularity for the compare of ZMM registers so that should be obvious.  I don't think there's a good way to use AVX512F to implement `strlen` or `memchr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of your code makes any sense.  You can't use `ax` as a mask register in instructions like `vaddps zmm0{k1}{z}, zmm1, zmm2`.  And `kmov` doesn't take an offset to extract from, and there's no syntax like `[k0 + 2]`.  If there was an extract instruction analogous to `pextrw`, it wouldn't use square brackets.

---

**And you can't get a 64-bit value into a mask register in the first place without AVX512BW**: the only mask-setting instructions in AVX512F use dword or qword elements and thus produce at most 16 mask bits.  And `kmov` / other `k` instructions are only available with up to 16-bit operand-size, like [`kunpcklbw`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/kunpckbw:kunpckwd:kunpckdq).

**A CPU with AVX512F but not AVX512BW might only have 16-bit wide `k` registers.**

**Without AVX512BW there's nothing you can do that reads or writes the upper bits of a `k` register.**

Except possibly `xsave` or `xsaveopt` or something; it doesn't require AVX512BW but it will dump the full contents of vector state to memory where you can maybe load 64-bit mask register values.  This is highly unlikely to be useful; I only mention it as an exception to the statement that there's nothing you can do without AVX512BW.

---

Don't avoid AVX512BW in code that depends on AVX512BW having put a 64-bit value in a mask register.